# Order of a group and cyclic group theory connection

Tags: group-theory

Just stuck on a problem. If group $G$ of order $6$ contains an element of order $6$, then prove that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $6$. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I should have provided some more info i.e. G itself is a group of order 6. That is why it has 6 elements and if an element has order 6 then the powers of the element cover the entire group. Consequently, the group is a cyclic group of order 6. I think that is how the proof has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic group $G$ is one such that there exists a $g \in G$ where every element of $G$ can be expressed as $g^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Essentially, given that $|g| = 6$, you just need to prove that $g^n$ is unique for all $n \in \{1, 2, ..., 6\}$.

To do this, assume that $g^n = g^m$ for $n \neq m$ and $n, m \in \{1, 2, ..., 6\}$ and arrive at a contradiction.